# How to add two classes to same .java file without nesting?

Tags: java, code-generation, javapoet

Result:

```
public class cls1 
{
    short f1;

    short f2;

    byte f3;

  }

  public class cls2 
{
    short f4;

    short f5;

    byte f6;

  }
```

Result not like this :

```
public class cls1 
{
    short f1;

    short f2;

    byte f3;

  public class cls2 
{
    short f4;

    short f5;

    byte f6;

  }
}
```

Comment: remove public key word in your first appraoch and let me know. there cannot be  2 classes with public modifier if one class is public then file name should be class. If there is no public class then you can keep any of the class. Here I am not talking about nested class but 2 separate classes

Comment: And read about java naming conventions. Class names should go UpperCase, always, even for examples.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can have multiple top level classes in single .java file, but only one of them can be public.

Comment: yes please. I added public by mistake, but i want to know if javapoet allows me to add two classes irrespective of access specifier to the same .java file.

Answer (score 0):

JavaPoet deliberately doesn’t support this. We recommend you use nesting or separate files instead.

Comment: with nesting, will the memory allocation be affected? How much memory will be allocated if I create instance of the outer class?

Comment: There’s no difference.